# Slicing element from sublist - Python

Tags: python, list, slice

I want to return the number 5 from this:

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I thought this would work but it is not:

```
print(list_1[1:1])
```

It returns an empty list.  It is Index 1 (second list) and position 1 (second number in the list).

Shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two separate operations:

```
sub_list = list_1[1]
item = sub_list[1]
# or shortly list_1[1][1]
```

What you did was calling the slice interface which has an interface of `[from:to:step]`. So it meant: "give me all the items **from** index 1 to **index** 1" (read about slicing for more information).

Answer (score 2):

list_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

then

```
list_1[0] == [1,2,3]
list_1[1] == [4,5,6]
```

then

```
list_1[1][1:1] == []  #slice starting from position '1', and around to the position before '1', effectively returning an empty list
list_1[1][1] == 5
```

*edit* corrections as from comments

Comment: `list_1[1][1:1] = 5` is not true. Also you should use `==` and not `=`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant to represent what each one is. replacing "=" with "==" would make each line "True"

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1[1][1]
```

The first [1] gives you [4, 5, 6]. The next [1] gives you 5

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a list:

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

You're question asks, why does

```
list_1[1:1]
```

Return `[]`?

Because you're asking for the objects from index 1 to index 1, which is nothing.

Take a simple list:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[1:1]
[]
```

This is also empty because you're asking for all objects from index 1 to index 1.

All the 2nd number does is say the maximum reach **non-inclusive**. So...

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[1:10000]
[2, 3]
>>> x[1:-1023]
[]
>>> x[1:2]
[2]
```

If the 1st number is equal to or greater than the 2nd number, you'll always end up with an empty list unless you change the **step** of the slice (if it's equal, it'll always be empty)

Of a 2-dimensional array, if you wanted the 2nd object of the 2nd list in the list:

```
>>> list_1[1]
[4, 5, 6]
>>> list_1[1][1]
5
```