# How do I print the first 2 elements of the first 2 sub-lists in a list of lists in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists and I want to print the first 2 elements of the first 2 sub-lists.

I don't know if I am approaching it in the wrong way but I don't get the desired output.

Here is my code:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]]

print(x[0:2])
print(x[0:2][0:2])
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

expected output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
[[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think you should try like x[1:2]i am attaching the link of similar issue solved in stack over flow that might help you [Stack over flow slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183851/slicing-element-from-sublist-python)

also how python slicing works link [python slicing works with description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)

Answer (score 3):

Something like that could do the trick:

```py
print([l[:2] for l in x[:2]])
[[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]
```

Explanation:

- `x[:2]` (or `x[0:2]`) gets the first 2 sublists.
- `for l in x[:2]` at each iteration assigns to `l` each of the sublists
- `l[:2]` takes the first 2 elements of the sublist.

Why `x[0:2][0:2]` doesn't work?

- `x` is a list of sublists.
- `x[0:2]` returns a list with the first 2 sublists.
- `x[0:2][0:2]` is the same to `(x[0:2])[0:2]` that's equivalent to `x[0:2]`, because it takes the first 2 sublists from the first 2 sublists.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]]

k=[]
for y in x[0:2]:
    k.append(y[0:2])

print(k)
#[[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a list.

Clearly you expect `x[:2]` to be a list as well containing two elements from `x`, regardless of their contents.

Now write out

```
y = x[:2]
print(y[:2])
```

Clearly, that will print the first two elements of `x`, regardless of the contents.

The way to access the element of a list instead of a sublist is with a single integer index or by iteration.

```
for y in x[:2]:
    print(y[:2])
```

You can iterate more compactly using a comprehension:

```
print(*(y[:2] for y in x[:2]), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can simply have your expected result with:

```
for item in x[:2]:
    print(item[0:2])
```

But if ever you had a homogeneous nested list (same number of rows and columns), you could convert it into a NumPy array and then use multidimensional slicing which is way easier. For example for a list like:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]]
```

You can do:

```
x = np.array(x)
print(x[:2, :2])
```